# Jasper Report can preview but cannot opening progarmmically

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

`Parse Error at line 2 column 434: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'uuid' is not allowed to appear in element 'jasperReport'. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 434; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute`

please help me this report can preview but not running grammatically.

Comment: Version of JR for "preview" must be the same with "open pragrammatically"

Comment: How are you trying programmatically. Where's the relevant code?